# Erro de propriedade não pode ser setada para o System.Double

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Peguei esse erro:

> The 'DataLib' property on 'Liberacao' could not be set to a
>   'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of type 'System.Single'

O que passa é que eu comentei a propriedade em minha Entity Model e também na lambda, assim:

```
public IEnumerable<Liberacao> getAutoriza(int idorcamento)
{
  var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
    .Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
    .ToList()
    .Select(lib => new Liberacao
    {
      TipoVenda = lib.TipoVenda,
      Vencimento = lib.Vencimento,
      Juros = lib.Juros,
      Entrada = lib.Entrada,
      Acrescimo = lib.Acrescimo,
      Desconto = lib.Desconto,
      Mensagem = lib.Mensagem,
      //DataLib = lib.DataLib,
      Vendedor = lib.Vendedor,
      Cliente = lib.Cliente,
      Filial = lib.Filial
    }).ToList();

  return lista;
}
```

Só nõ entendo o porque do erro persistir no mesmo campo. Já dei um clean na solution e nada.

Comment: qual linha acontece o erro ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, como é uma expressão lambda, ele apenas no final da expressão, apresenta o erro, já que ele lê a expressão de uma única vez

Comment: como está a declaração deste campo ?

Comment: `[Column("DATALIB")]
 public float DataLib { get; set; }`

Comment: e qual o tipo da coluna no banco de dados ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64379/discussion-between-rovann-linhalis-and-pnet).

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você esta dando um `.ToList()` entre o método `.Select(lib => new Liberacao)` e o método `.Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)`, isso força o meu IQueryable a ser executado e a parte do .Select() já não é mais manipulação de SQL, e sim um LINQ comum.

O que acontece é que seu campo `[Column("DATALIB")]` é NULLABLE sem valor, quando você da o ToList, como eu comentei, você força a execução do SQL retornando um `SELECT *` do banco de dados. Esse valor de DATALIB nulo vai conflitar com o seu float primitivo:

```
[Column("DATALIB")] public float DataLib { get; set; }
```

Perceba que o campo float não aceita null, caso queira que ele aceita use `Nullable<float> ou float?` ou coloquei um valor default para seu DATALIB.

Comment: Quando eu tiro o ToList() antes do Select me dá esse erro: `The entity or complex type 'Inet.AutorizadorService.Infra.Data.Context.Liberacao' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`. Essa forma com o ToList() antes do select, eu peguei aqui no SOpt com um post do LINQ

Comment: Você não pode instanciar uma classe do seu contexto em uma query que vai ser transformada, cria um Data Transfer Object chamado LiberacaoModel para isso ou algo do gênero. Sobre retirar o nulo do banco, apenas adicione o DataAnnotation [Required] encima da propriedade. Você esta editando diretamente o banco de dados? É recomendável que você utilize Migrations para fazer essas alterações.

Comment: E como eu faria isso? Basta criar uma classe semelhante a essa, mas sem atribuir entidades do BD? E como eu ligaria a DTO à classe principal?

Comment: Parecida, se você não precisa de determinada propriedade não é necessário replicar no Model, ficaria algo como: `Select(lib => new LiberacaoModel { TipoVenda = lib.TipoVenda  })` parecido com o que você fez. Para retornar ela a ser uma Liberacao se necessário, você vai precisar mapear ela.

Comment: Somente assim não estou entendo bem. Vou ler alguma coisa e tentar. O que deixa preocupado é que eu fiz um outro serviço, da mesma forma, mas com o banco criado por mim. Esse, foi um script que meu colega me passou e dá erro nesse campo, mesmo eu comentando ele na Entity Model.

Comment: Gabriel, não entendi ao certo como usar o DTO e o AutoMapper, para fazer isso funcionar. Já crie minha classe LiberacaoDTO e o que mais eu faço?

Comment: Use sua DTO para configurar quais propriedades você quer dentro do seu SELECT igualmente você fez com Libertacao, com isso você terá um IQueryable<LiberacaoDTO>. Sobre o AutoMapper ele é um package e precisa ser configurado.

Comment: Cara, tá confuso, talvez por eu nunca ter feito isso. Conhece algum tuto que ajude a entender isso?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:
No construtor da classe DTO eu fiz isso para cada campo double(float não deu certo)

```
public LiberacaoDTO()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {

                //string userName = null;
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoDTO, Liberacao>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Juros,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Juros.ToString("C2")
                        ));

                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(e => e.Entrada,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Entrada.ToString("C2")
                ));
            });
        }
```

E na classe que tem o método fiz assim, tratando o nulo ou 0:

```
var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
           .Where(m => m.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
           //.GroupBy(m => m.EmployeeId)
           .Select(m => new LiberacaoDTO
           {
               TipoVenda = m.TipoVenda,
               //Entrada = m.Entrada != 0 ? m.Entrada : 0,
               Juros = m.Juros != 0 ? m.Juros : 0,
               Entrada = m.Entrada != 0 ? m.Entrada : 0,
               MaxComi = m.MaxComi,
               Cliente = m.Cliente,
               Filial = m.Filial
           })
           .ToList();

            return lista;
```

Minha preocupação é que no banco continua float e na model eu coloquei double, pois float estava dando erro, o mesmo erro de cast relatado acima. Se alguém achar que eu terei problemas com isso, estou aceitando sugestões e correções.

Comment: Postei que com float não funcionou, mas agora está ok. Acho que era por causa do null, ainda que não estava tendo problemas com o `ToString()` naquele momento, mas estava dando o pau. Removi o nullable e agora funciona com float, bem, está ok e posso mapear com o mesmo tipo do banco dessa vez.